# JavaScript iterate loop every x number of times in same loop?

Tags: javascript

I am not sure how to phrase this, so please re-title this question if it doesn't make sense. Anyways, this is what I am trying to do.

I have a variable with the length of 9.
And then I have another variable with the length of 3.

How do I write a loop that iterates through all 9 but starts over every third time?

**For example: I have this,**

```
x = 3;
l = 9;

for ( var i = 0; i < l; i++)
{ 
     console.log(i + 1);
}

output = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

**The output I want to create**

```
output = 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3
```

I was thinking there might be away to do this with an if statement or possibly modulus, but wasn't quite sure how to implement it. What would be a good way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use two `for(){…}` loops, one nested in the other?

Comment: `console.log(i % x + 1)`

Comment: @LightStyle, Yeah that is what I was looking for... I must have been doing it wrong when I tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = 3;
l = 9;

for ( var i = 0; i < l; i++)
{ 
     console.log(i % x + 1);
}
```

output = 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/BgBGL/

Comment: I thought you could do it with modulus, I must have been doing it wrong. This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I missed it at first as well.

Comment: I'm crying, code snipped with syntax errors won. :(

Comment: Don't cry, what syntax errors? Or are you referring to that you finally saw what works and used for your answer?

Comment: Defining variables without var is a crime. If you keep that habit you will have global variables breaking your code base eventually. ? what? are you kidding me, I never used your answer.. I have my own style and I can define my variables correctly (at least).

Comment: And if you keep assuming OP gives you their whole scripts... well, I guess nothing will happen. So first: those are not syntax errors even if that was OP's full script, second: how do you know they're not defined earlier? Can you see something we don't? ... Awesome to see you can define your own... I, on the other hand, used what OP gave me. Your style changes frequently.

Comment: Just FYI, I am using `var x = somevar;` or whatever in my actual code that was something I had just typed up quick to illustrate my problem.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck that's my point exactly (if you didn't define those properly, they you wouldn't define the iterator as well), don't worry about that guy... They are everywhere these days...

Comment: Sure, when some beginner programmer comes around he doesn't know that. This is why it makes sense to define them. @Shomz is just acting like a kid. tbh. well, I hope that time serves you better.

Comment: @MaunoV. What's wrong with you, seriously? Why would he know to define the iterator variable and not the others? I hope you stopped crying, now go learn what syntax errors are, and stop spamming here.

Comment: @Shomz I can see that your stubborn, it hinders you from learning to be better. Just answered to your comments with same attitude than you to mine in the first place. You obviously have a bad day irl or something. Keep it that way, ok? lets act more professionally here at least. thnx

Comment: @MaunoV. Asking you to point the syntax errors you mentioned - no reply. Accusing me instead of not being able to define vars - failed again as those are not my vars, and yes, there might be a reason OP didn't define vars in this snippet, imagine that! So I'd say I'm fact-oriented rather than stubborn. Something that actually might help **you** learn something... Ending this stupid debate now, have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Embrace the modulus:

```
function expand(length, loop_length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    console.log(i % loop_length + 1);
  } 
}
expand(9, 3) // =>  1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop from a min value to a max value a specific number of times, the easiest way is just to have 2 loops, like this:

```
var min = 1, max = 3, times = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    for (var j = min; j <= max; j++) {
         console.log(j);
    }
}
```

Or if you want to fix total length of the sequence, then yes, you can do it with a single loop and a little bit of math:

```
var min = 1, max = 3, totalLength = 9;
for (var i = 0; i < totalLength; i++) {
    console.log((i % (max - min + 1)) + min);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that case, this works:

```
x = 3;
l = 9;

for ( var i = 0; i < l; i++)
{ 
     var num=(i %(x+1)) || 1;
     console.log(num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go mad with following syntax:

```
var i = 0;

do {
  console.log(i++ % 3 + 1);
} while (i < 9);
```

Alternative, you could define `3` and `9` as a variable also.

I took an advantage of the fact that calling `i++` will display old variable and increases it by 1 after, so I saved some bits!

See: **[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sHt4B/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 3;
l = 9;

for ( var i = 0; i <= l; i++)
{ 
  for ( var j = 1; j <= x; j++)
   { 
     console.log(j);
   }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you test this. How are j + x going to give 1 when x is 3, and j is >= 0?

Comment: Better, there are two more things - the outer loop will run 10 times instead of 9 and the inner one 3 times each, making the total number of printed numbers 30 instead of 9.

Comment: I tested it and it gives 123 nine times. but you're right 30 loop is far answer from the main question.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad - it's 27 instead of 9. :) The easiest fix is probably: `for ( var i = 0; i < l/x; i++)` for the outer loop.